# Define function with variable change and integrate

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I have just started working with Mathematica and I am stuck with something that should be pretty simple, but I cannot find the solution. I want to define a function and then integrate it within a certain interval. The function is defined as follows

```
w[x_, y_] := With[{r = sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, 100[1 - (r/0.1)^2] exp[-(r/0.1)^2]]
```

And the integral is just the squared function between `x=[-1,1]` and `y=[-1,1]`

```
Integrate[w[x_, y_]^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

But the answer I get is just

\begin{equation}
\int _{-1}^1\int _{-1}^1\left(100\left(1-100. \text{sqrt}\left(\text{x$\_$}{}^2+\text{y$\_$}{}^2\right){}^2\right)\right){}^2 \exp \left(-100. \text{sqrt}\left(\text{x$\_$}{}^2+\text{y$\_$}{}^2\right){}^2\right){}^2dydx
\end{equation}

whereas I would like to get the numerical result.

Comment: `w[x_, y_]^2` should be `w[x, y]^2`. The `_` specifies that it's a function variable in the definition. Pass the variables of integration in to the function to get them to substitute. One other thing: built-in functions use capital letters. So `sqrt` and `exp` should be `Sqrt` and `Exp`. Maybe also see [this](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/function-definitions/)?

Comment: and `100[ 2]` is not `100 (2) --> 200`

Comment: As noted, capitalization matters. Use `Exp[]` and `Sqrt[]`. Also, do not use square brackets for grouping, as you did with `100[1 - (r/0.1)^2]`; parentheses are meant for that: `100 (1 - (r/0.1)^2)`

Comment: Got it, thank you all. Should I delete the question? I am aware is rather a simple one and only because I am completely new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of syntaxes errors. After correcting it looks as follows:

```
w[x_, y_] := 
 100 (1 - (r/0.1)^2) Exp[-(r/0.1)^2] /. r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
Integrate[w[x, y]^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
(*  78.5  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Yup, got it. Thanks.